# $_COOKIE and subdomains

Tags: php, cookies

I've written a cookie for my domain + subdomain:

```
setcookie("visitor", $visitor, time()+60*60*24*365, "/", ".mydomain.net");
```

but when I try to read it from within subdomain.mydomain.net, it's empty. Could it be that $_COOKIE[] tries to read the cookie for the subdomain instead of reading the global one? How do I fix this?
TIA
Steven

**Edit**
Happens in both Firefox and IE8

Answer (score 1):

You should check in your browser if the cookie actually exists for `.mydomain.net` (be sure the www part is excluded).

If that's the case then you should be able to read it from any `.mydomain.net` sub-domain using `$_COOKIE['visitor']` in PHP.

Just in case try dumping the `$_COOKIE` data by doing `print_r($_COOKIE);`

Comment: Grazie della risposta! The cookie exists alright; it is correctly read on the pages of http://mydomain.net.

Comment: @stevenvh: Prego :) . Is there a cookies set for 'visitor' on subdomain.mydomain.net? This would overwrite the 'visitor' on .mydomain.net

Comment: no (inglese: "no" ;-)), there are no cookies except the global one.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem when I was trying to set the cookie while in the subdomain. **After I set the cookie from the top domain**, everything worked great.  Something about setting the cookie from the subdomain will not set the cookie.